# How to add a new column to an existing table in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to add a new column in my Front-App  and send it to the api to add a new column to  existing table with Sequelize with the same name i add it in Front,and update the model.I have seen addColumn but i don't understand where and how to use it.
If somebody can help with that i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query interface](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/query-interface/#obtaining-the-query-interface) for this. Whenever you are making an API call, read the request and a column using `addColumn` as you said.

`queryInterface.addColumn(<TableName>, 'ColumnName', { type: <DataType> });`

Comment: i only have a doubt , it will update the model for further use of that table ??